# How do I write a program where it shows the average of the average for students whose age are 20 or below. Using (for loop) in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

Basically I need to use (`for` loop) in Oracle SQL Developer to show the average of the average for students whose age is 20 or below. Down Below is the students' table

[image: The Table]

Comment: Good luck! Be sure to ask a question when you get stuck

Comment: Thanks! and I'm actually stuck at this question

Comment: I presume HoneyBadger meant to say that you should post **code** you wrote, but it doesn't work as you'd want it to.

Comment: You don't need a FOR loop to do that.

Comment: I actually do need to use for loop for this question.

Comment: I do wish that when instructors are trying to teach a given technique they would use scenarios for which the subject technique is actually the optimal solution.  As it is students may learn the technique, but they also come away thinking - incorrectly - "ah, this technique is how you solve this business problem".

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a homework (funny requirements for simple situations). Anyway, see if something like this helps.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_avg number;
  3    l_sum number := 0;
  4    l_cnt number := 0;
  5  begin
  6    for cur_r in (select avg from test where age <= 20) loop
  7      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
  8      l_sum := l_sum + cur_r.avg;
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    if l_cnt > 0 then
 12       l_avg := l_sum / l_cnt;
 13    end if;
 14
 15    dbms_output.put_line('Average is ' || nvl(to_char(l_avg), 'unknown'));
 16  end;
 17  /
Average is 68

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT AVG("AVG") FROM students WHERE age<=20
```

Comment: It didn't work plus I need to use for loop

Comment: Oh, it is your requirement to use for loop... Lemme think.

Comment: Try using "AVG" instead of [Avg]

Comment: Yah its a requirement to use it